# Not able to connect to mysql on a remote server using docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, yaml, nestjs

I want to dockerize a nest.js project that connects to a remote mysql server. I am trying to connect to a remote server database but I am getting this error `unable to connect to the database 127.0.0.1:3306`. The port is not 3306 and the host is not localhost.

```
FROM node:16 As development

WORKDIR /api
RUN mkdir -p /api/data
COPY . .

ENV $(cat .env | xargs)

#RUN npm install
ENV PORT=${PORT} \
    NODE_ENV=production \
    DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST} \
    DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME} \
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} \
    DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT} \
    DATABASE_USERNAME=${DATABASE_USERNAME} \
    DATABASE_TYPE=${DATABASE_TYPE} \
    REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST} \
    REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT} \
    REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD} \
    JWT_SECRET=xxxx \
    JWT_EXPIRES_IN=${JWT_EXPIRES_IN} \
    EMAIL_SERVER=${EMAIL_SERVER} \
    EMAIL_ADDRESS=${EMAIL_ADDRESS} \
    EMAIL_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}

COPY .env /api

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

I have tried several approaches but could not get this resolved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using these variables, especially `DATABASE_HOST` and `DATABASE_PORT`?  (Should you set them when you run the container, rather than compiling them into an image, so you can reuse the same image in other environments?)

Comment: After building the image, I opened the bash and set all environment variables needed. In the container if I hardcode the variables in the application connection file, it works fine, but if I try to pick from the environment variables, it chooses the container IF and port.

Comment: Your container should only be running the Node application; there shouldn't be a step of "open a bash".  In your actual code, how do you use these environment variables?

Comment: Yes, I have used the environment variables. When I run printenv, I see them, but the application is not picking them.